# How to make Xpath Contains() to search the exact match while parsing xml?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

My sample xml:

```
 <root>
    <test>
    <para>This is a <comment>new</comment> para</para>
    </test>
    </root>
```

My XPath will be:

```
 root/test/para[text()=contains(., 'This is a new para')];
```

It will work fine as it contains the same text value.

If the text content in the xml is changed at the end.

```
 <root>
    <test>
    <para>This is a <comment>new</comment> para hightlighted</para>
    </test>
    </root>
```

It should return false. Instead I am getting true.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The XPath contains() function does what the spec says. You can't change what it does. You want the '=' operator. And by the way, XPath evaluation happens AFTER you parse the XML, not WHILE you are parsing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given:

```
<root>
    <test>
        <para id="1">This is a <comment>new</comment> para</para>
        <para id="2">This is a <comment>new</comment> para hightlighted</para>
    </test>
</root>
```

this XPath expression:

```
root/test/para[. = 'This is a new para']
```

matches `para id="1"` but not `para id="2"`.